# Rewrite an url with htaccess

Tags: php, apache

I would rewrite an url

```
http://mydomain/index.php?s=profil
```

to

```
http://localhost/profil
```

I have try this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?s=$1 [L]
```

But not work (error 500).

Comment: Why not just `^(.*)$`

Comment: You mean the other way around?  You want user to type `/profil` and have the request rewritten behind the scenes to `index.php?s=profil`?

Comment: Find your Apache error log, it will explain the error in more detail.

Comment: Look like you wanted it the other way around coz the usual one, if the url is domain/profile , redirect the page to domain/index.php?s=profil. Are you sure about that? The purpose of having htaccess is to have the clean url work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you wanted your url http://urdomain.com/profile to show content from http://urdomain.com/index.php?s=profil, an example of how you do it is  this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule    ^content/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    index.php?s=$1    [NC,L]
```

This rule will redirect your page urdomain.com/content/Alphanumeric123 to index.php?s = $1

Explaination:

```
[a-z] - lower case characters
[A-Z] - Upper case characters
[0-9] - numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite before the RewriteRule:

RewriteEngine On